# PHP timeout during simple connection to MySQL - on win2k8 64bit IIS 7 / FastCGI php - new install

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7, windows-server-2008, fastcgi

I installed PHP/FastCGI and Mysql on w2k8 64bit IIS7.

PHPinfo() loads fine, and MySQL extension is properly installed. PHP displays echo commands.

MySQL also works fine through the MySQL Command Line Client. I can create DBs, tables and users.

However MySQL does not respond and the PHP script times out when simply connecting with mysql_connect("localhost","user goes here","pass goes here");

I miss win2k3.

Any ideas?

> PHP Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 9 PHP Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 9 PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Seems to be a [**right-out bug**](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45150).

Comment: yes! that worked! why is this happening? should it be fixed to work on localhost as well?

Comment: thanks for helping me out. This site needs to feed responses in real-time.

Comment: @webdevbytes: You're welcome. Heh, that's the Stack Overflow phenomenon, I'm often dazzled too :) There's simply an awful lot of people here.